# javascript array restart counting

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have this piece of code:

```
  //var data.name is declared somewhere else, e.g. "Sherlock". It changes  often.
  recents[recents.length] = data.name;
  idThis = "recent" + recents.length;
  if(recents.length >= 7) {
  recents[0]=recents[7];
  recents[1]=recents[8];
  recents[2]=recents[9];
  recents[3]=recents[10];
  recents[4]=recents[11];
  recents[5]=recents[12];
  recents[6]=recents[13];
  recents[7]=recents[14];
  recents[0]=recents[15];
  recents[1]=recents[16];
  recents[2]=recents[17];
  //etc
  idThis = "recent" + (recents.length -7);
}
document.getElementById(idThis).innerHTML = data.name;
```

My question is how do I automate the `recents[0]=recents[7]
      recents[1]=recents[8]` etc?
The point is that the `recent` id  can't be higher than 6, otherwise the rest of the code won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to get a [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) from the original array. I'm not sure which slice you want, but here's how to get the first 8 items and the last 8 items, maybe one of those is what you want:

```
// Get the first 8 items from recents.
var first8 = recents.slice(0, 8);
// Get the last 8 items from recents.
var last8 = recents.slice(-8);
// first8 and last8 now contain UP TO 8 items each.
```

Of course, if your `recents` array doesn't have 8 items, the results from `slice` will be less than 8 items.

If you want to delete a range in the `recents` array, you can use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
// Delete the first 8 items of recents.
recents.splice(0, 8);
// recents[0] is now effectively the value of the former recents[8] (and so on)
```

You can also use the return value of `splice` to get the items that were deleted:

```
// Delete and get the first 8 items of recents.
var deletedItems = recents.splice(0, 8);
// You could now add them to the end, for example:
recents = recents.concat(deletedItems);
```

Answer (score 1):

**INIT:**

var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

**ADD last element:**

```
fruits.push("Kiwi");
```

Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango,Kiwi

**DELETE 1st element:**

```
fruits.shift();
```

Orange,Apple,Mango,Kiwi

**SOLUTION:**

```
function add(fruit) {
    if(fruits.length > 6) {
        fruits.shift();
        fruits.push(fruit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Just one problem: I have to push the kiwi to the first place, and remove the first object before that

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
for (i = 0; i < recents.length; i++) { 
    recents[i]=recents[i % 7];
}
```

Comment: The `i < 7` needs to be `i < recents.length` for this to do anything. Also, this would just repeat the first 8 items over and over again, I'm not sure if that was the desired effect.